# Unable to update textArea field from Save Commandbutton in Apex Custom Controller Extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have an object VF_Page_Update__c which has a picklist field called VF_Page_Picklist__c and a textArea(255) field Update__c. I am dynamically showing the picklist values in the Visualforce page I created called 'UpdatePageVF'. Now what I want is when I change the picklist value in VF_Page_Picklist__c and change the text in Update__c from the VF page and click on Save button, then that value will be updated in database. Currently, the VF_Page_Picklist__c value gets changed, but the value in Update__c remains the same old value even after clicking on Save. What am I doing wrong?

Apex class 'UpdateController'

```
public with sharing class Update_Controller {
public VF_Page_Update__c mcc {get; private set;}
private final VF_Page_Update__c speaker;

private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
public Update_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
 mcc= [select Id,name,VF_Page_Picklist__c, Update__c from VF_Page_Update__c WHERE id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
  this.speaker = (VF_Page_Update__c)stdController.getRecord();
        this.stdController = stdController;
  }
  public List<SelectOption> getVFPageList()
{
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
 VF_Page_Update__c.VF_Page_Picklist__c.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   }       
   return options;
}
 public PageReference saveClose() {


     update speaker;

      return null;


    }

}
```

Visualforce page 'UpdatePageVF'

```
<apex:page standardController="VF_Page_Update__c" extensions="Update_Controller" >
   <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">

            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
<apex:inputField value="{!mcc.Update__c}"/> <p/>
<apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!VF_Page_Update__c.VF_Page_Picklist__c}"
         size="1" required="true">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!VFPageList}"/>

</apex:selectList>


       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveClose}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

This code only updates the VF_Page_Picklist__c but not the Update__c.Please help and provide me the corrected code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

You don't actually need two objects of VF_Page_Update__c in the Controller.

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Update_Controller {
    //public VF_Page_Update__c mcc {get; private set;}
    public VF_Page_Update__c speaker;

    //private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public Update_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
      this.speaker = (VF_Page_Update__c)stdController.getRecord();
      //this.stdController = stdController;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getVFPageList()
    {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

       Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
       VF_Page_Update__c.VF_Page_Picklist__c.getDescribe();
       List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

       for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
       {
          options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
       }       
       return options;
    }
    public PageReference saveClose() {
         update speaker;
          return null;
    }

}
```

**VF PAGE**

```
<apex:page standardController="VF_Page_Update__c" extensions="Update_Controller" >
   <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">

            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
<apex:inputField value="{!VF_Page_Update__c.Update__c}"/> <p/>
<apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!VF_Page_Update__c.VF_Page_Picklist__c}"
         size="1" required="true">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!VFPageList}"/>

</apex:selectList>


       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveClose}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works!! Can you tell me where I was going wrong?

Comment: You were updating an Object that was not referring to the Text area in VF it was a different object. So you just need 1 object